# Functional ReactJS - Passing Data/Arguments to Callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Take the following code:

```
const Search = props => {
    return (
        <div id="search">
            <h2>Live Search</h2>
            <input type="text" onChange={ props.onInput } />
        </div>
    )
}

export default Search
```

Is it possible to pass arguments to `props.onInput` (specifically the `value` attribute of `<input>`). I know I can create this as a class instead, and create a handler that passes data to `props.onInput` but I was just wondering if it's possible to do this in a functional way.

Comment: Your onChange function will receive an event, you can take the value from the event: `<Search onInput={({ target: { value } }) => { console.log(value); }} />`

Comment: @DragosRizescu I don't want to pass an event. The function takes a `query` string to make a call to an API.

Comment: you are not passing an event, you are receiving one from which you can take your `query` string. Honestly, writing, `onChange={ (e) => props.onInput(e.target.value) }` is almost the same thing as what I wrote, the different being the you treat the `event` you receive in a different place ;)

Comment: Ah sorry so you did. Ignore my last comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of arrow function like `<input type="text" onChange={ (e) => props.onInput(e.target.value) } />`

See a snippet below

```js
const Search = props => {
    return (
        <div id="search">
            <h2>Live Search</h2>
            <input type="text" onChange={ (e) => props.onInput(e.target.value) } />
        </div>
    )
}

const onInput = (val) => {
    console.log(val)
}
ReactDOM.render(<Search onInput={onInput}/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"><div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Synthetic Event to pass the value to the callback.

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html

If you would like to pass only the value, you can use `e.currentTarget.value`.

> From currentTarget documentation:
>
> It always refers to the element the event handler has been attached to as opposed to event.target which identifies the element on which the event occurred.

```
const Search = props => {
    return (
        <div id="search">
            <h2>Live Search</h2>
            <input
                type="text"
                onChange={e => props.onInput(e.currentTarget.value) } />
        </div>
    )
}

export default Search
```